# Best way to disable flycheck checkdoc warnings on specific elisp directory?

Tags: flycheck

I use `flycheck` with `flycheck-elisp-checkdoc` checker active and find them fairly useful.

Still, I find it irritating to be nagged about missing `(provide)`, section headers (`;;; Code`, ...), package metadata and similar things while I am editing my `~/emacs/etc` (that's `~/.emacs` split into smaller pieces). Those files are short configuration snippets and adding those comments would only make them longer and less readable.

So, what is the best way to disable those warnings in this very place (but only there, the same reminders are very useful once I edit my true lisp modules...)?

*I do not really mind whether it would mean disabling flycheck-elisp-checkdoc checker for flycheck in this very dir, or reconfiguring checkdoc in this ery place, or something in-between – although the latter case would also handle other ways of spawning checkdoc…*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set `flycheck-disabled-checkers` to `(emacs-lisp-checkdoc)` via file or directory variables, i.e. `M-x add-file-local-variable RET flycheck-disabled-checkers RET (emacs-lisp-checkdoc)` or `add-dir-local-variable RET emacs-lisp-mode RET flycheck-disabled-checkers RET (emacs-lisp-checkdoc)` respectively.

See [Syntax checkers](http://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/user/syntax-checkers.html) in the Flycheck manual for more information.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I knew about ```flycheck-disabled-checkers``` but  forgot that it can be set via dir-locals.

Comment: (still curious whether sth similar can be configured also for ```M-x checkdoc```, but that's not that important)

Comment: Turns out there is minor annoyance in this solution. Whenever I start emacs, I get warning ```Warning (emacs): Failed to load file /home/marcink/DEV_hg/emacs/etc/.dir-locals.el: (invalid-function (emacs-lisp-mode (flycheck-disabled-checkers emacs-lisp-checkdoc)))
``` (flycheck is loaded by one of those etc files, but looks like .dir-locals is interpreted when they are processed).

Comment: This is an issue in your configuration.  Neither Emacs nor Flycheck load dir locals.  You probably have some code in your init file which loads all files in etc/.

Comment: Of course I have such code, that's the point of using this dir...  Ahh, you mean my code reads .dir-locals.el too? Will take a look

Comment: Yes, good point, my loop iterated over any .el files in etc directory, so catched .dir-locals.el too. Thank you for hint.

Comment: If you wish to put this in your `init.el` simply add: `(setq-default flycheck-disabled-checkers '(emacs-lisp-checkdoc))`.